# Slow exporting of sql data to csv by Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, teradata

I need to export a large amount of data (from TERADATA by an sql query) to a csv file using PowerShell.
The process is working but is very very slow.
I am using this code for exporting :

```
($DataSet.Tables[0] | ConvertTo-Csv  -delimiter "|" -NoTypeInformation )   -replace '"', "" | Out-File $extractFile -Force
```

$extractFile is the path where I want to put my csv file.

Do you have any idea why is it that slow and how i can deal with that ?

Comment: *large amount of data* = you better use a TPT Export for this.

Comment: Do you have any documentation on how to export with TPT ? I am new to teradata and i didn't find a good documentation on TPT

Comment: Check the TPT User Guide http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/index.html#page/Load_and_Unload_Utilities/B035_2445_035K/2445ch06.100.08.html#ww10985228

Comment: I used BTEQ, FastExport, but the highest speed I achieved was with SAS using BulkLoad over ODBC. We are talking about 1B+ records in a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `StreamWriter`

```
$Stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] $extractFile
$DataSet.Tables[0] | ConvertTo-Csv  -delimiter "|" -NoTypeInformation | % { $Stream.WriteLine($_.Replace('"', '')) }
$Stream.Close()
```

Edit: Adding the `Replace` directly in WriteLine made it quicker as well.

You could also utilize `Measure-Command` to identify what part is slowing down and what changes speeds it up.

Comment: I have this error  : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At E:\PowerShell\script\Spaceman.ps1:26 char:77
+ $DataSet.Tables[0] | ConvertTo-Csv  -delimiter "|" -NoTypeInformation | % { $Str ...

Comment: Is it the `StringWriter` or `Replace` that is causing this?

Comment: StringWriter i think, it's the one underlined

Comment: Can you try changing to `% { if($_) { $Stream.WriteLine($_.Replace('"', '')) } }` ?